# Symfony2: Pass _route To Event Listener Service

Tags: php, symfony

I need to pass the '_route' from the container into an event listener, along with a route attribute. In other words, I need the listener service to become container aware without going through the overhead of passing the whole service_container into the event listener class.

I've seen code examples similar to this:

```
services: 
    root.path.locator: 
        class: Acme\Bundle\HelloBundle\Util\RootLocator 
        arguments: ['%kernel.root_dir%']
```

In a controller I would use something like the code below to grab the "_route":

```
$request = $this->container->get('request');
$routeName = $request->get('_route');
```

However, in the event listener, I don't have that available.

How can I accomplish the above?

Thanks,

JB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `scope` to `request` on the service xml tag. That will automatically inject the Request object, then set @request as an argument. In yaml, set `scope: request` and `arguments: [@request]`.

Comment: Interesting. While the Request object is passed in, it looks like the Request parameters array is empty, which should contain the _route parameter. Am I overlooking something?